# Alternating colors for iOS UIViews (like when used in a tablerow)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

This code is not working but I think it is very close. I haven't been able to get the many permutations I tried to work. Is this even possible?

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor (i % 2) == 0 ? cyanColor : whiteColor];
```

Has anyone tried this or know how this code can be corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work that way.
You need to write

```
myView.backgroundColor =  (i % 2 == 0)? [UIColor cyanColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
```